# ImmutableMap and Map are incompatible?

Tags: java, dropwizard

I am following [this tutorial](http://howtodoinjava.com/dropwizard/dropwizard-basic-auth-security-example/) in order to try and add authentication to my dropwizard based API.

I am having an issue in that the tutorial gets to the point where we need to write an authenticator class, and uses the following code :

```
private static final Map<String, Set<String>> VALID_USERS = ImmutableMap.of(
    "guest", ImmutableSet.of(),
    "user", ImmutableSet.of("USER"),
    "admin", ImmutableSet.of("ADMIN", "USER")
);
```

This, from what I can gather is a way of setting up some roles so that they can later be used when limiting access to certain endpoints - but I am getting an error on this code :

```
Incompatible Types

Required : Map <path to Map class here>
Found : ImmutableMap <path to ImmutableMap class here>
```

Now, I realize they are different types,and I have used maps before, but ImmutableMaps are new territory for me, so I was kind of relying on this code from the tutorial working.

If anyone could let me know how to fix it, that would be awesome, and if you can explain why it was broken as well, that would be even better! thanks!

Comment: `ImmutableMap.<String, Set<String>>of(...)`. In general, `GenericClass<Subclass>` is not an instance of `GenericClass<Superclass>`.

Comment: A `Map<String, Set<String>>` is not a `Map<String, ImmutableSet<String>>`. So you need a `Map<String, ? extends Set<String>>`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider or `Map<String, ImmutableSet<String>> VALID_USERS`.

Comment: @AndyTurner sure, or that. Prefer the wildcard with the interface though.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I'd prefer the strong statement that "`VALID_USERS` isn't mutable" from `ImmutableMap<S, ImmutableSet<S>>`. Wildcards should only really be used in method parameters.

Comment: Those were some quick replies! But neither of them seem to work! :( maybe I am doing something wrong - could you perhaps show me what you mean in an answer comment? I need that anyway so I can mark as best answer for the next person coming along with this problem :)

Comment: Can you add the error messages?

Comment: It is in the question, at the bottom :)

Comment: Are you using some custom map interface?

Answer (score 1):

`ImmutableMap.of` will infer generic type arguments of `<String, ImmutableSet<String>>` in this case. You might have to explicitly specify the type args:

```
private static final Map<String, Set<String>> VALID_USERS = ImmutableMap.<String, Set<String>>of(
    "guest", ImmutableSet.of(),
    "user", ImmutableSet.of("USER"),
    "admin", ImmutableSet.of("ADMIN", "USER")
);
```

Comment: This certainly helps, but when I do that, I now get a different error on the "ImmutableSet.of()" line, which says : "Wrong second argument type, found ImmutableSet, required Set"

Comment: Same problem. `Map<String, ImmutableSet<String>>` is not a subtype of `Map<String, Set<String>>`.